# Integrating Balanced Payment Gateway(Active Merchant Based) in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, activemerchant, balanced-payments

I have installed active_merchant gem in my application(Spree Commerce), while configuring the payment method in spree commerce

[image]

it is asking for LOGIN and ON BEHALF OF URI, can any one explain what it is asking for. do I need to setup test account at

> https://support.balancedpayments.com

or it is something else
I am getting this error while purchansint a product from front-store with credit test card number 4242424242424242

> ActiveMerchant::Billing::BalancedGateway::Error in
> Spree::CheckoutController#update
>
> Invalid login credentials supplied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another user shared some basic steps to configure Spree with Balanced.

https://github.com/balanced/balanced-docs/issues/287

Comment: Thanks foe you reply Remear, I have solved the issues my self last night.
by the help from this [Creates a new BalancedGateway](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/balanced.rb)

  **# Creates a new BalancedGateway
    #
    # The gateway requires that a valid api_key be passed in the +options+
    # hash.
    # ==== Options
    # * <tt>:login</tt> -- The Balanced API Secret (REQUIRED)**